# Qt buggy form rendering in MacOS when widget visibility changes

Tags: forms, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, visibility

I have a couple of radio buttons on the form and 2 line inputs.
I want only one of those inputs to be visible depending on which option is checked.

So, every time user clicks I set visibility for both lineedits via
setVisible() function.

It works just fine on Windows, but on MacOS I see artifacts. Behind the visible lineedit I see "remains" of hidden lineedit:
[image]

Is there any hack to fix this on mac os?

PyQt version 5

**EDIT:**

As per request, bellow is example to verify. Run this in MacOS with python 3.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setVisible(False)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("LineEdit 1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setVisible(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setVisible(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("LineEdit 2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Option 1"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Option 2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.ui.radioButton.clicked.connect(self.update_visibility)
        self.ui.radioButton_2.clicked.connect(self.update_visibility)

    def update_visibility(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setVisible(self.ui.radioButton.isChecked())
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.setVisible(self.ui.radioButton_2.isChecked())

    def exec(self):
        self.window.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

def main():
    a = App()
    a.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Example added .

Comment: Why do not you use a QStackedWidget to toggle the visibility of the QLineEdits?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Thanks. Stacked widget is definitely a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the error that signals is a Qt bug or an incompatibility of some driver.

My solution goes in another direction, instead of hiding the QLineEdits you can use a QStackedWidget next to QButtonGroup to set the visibility of the QLineEdits.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.import_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(
            "import from file", checked=True
        )
        self.download_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(
            "Download via magnet link"
        )
        self.import_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText="LineEdit 1"
        )
        self.download_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText="LineEdit 2"
        )

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.import_radiobutton)
        lay.addWidget(self.download_radiobutton)
        stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        stacked.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum
        )
        lay.addWidget(stacked)
        lay.addStretch()
        buttongroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
        buttongroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(stacked.setCurrentIndex)
        for button, lineedit in zip(
            (self.import_radiobutton, self.download_radiobutton),
            (self.import_lineedit, self.download_lineedit),
        ):
            ix = stacked.addWidget(lineedit)
            buttongroup.addButton(button, ix)
        self.resize(640, 480)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, temporary solution is to call repaint() on window or on each buggy element every time. It looks jerky however. Any better solutions?